# In Android, aborting an AsyncTask from a postDelayed runnable

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpurlconnection, runnable, postdelayed

In `Main UI`:

- Create a dialog without a cancel button
- Start `AsyncTask` which in turn starts a `HttpURLConnection` in the `doInBackground()`
- After about 10 seconds the following is started in the `Main UI` thread via a `postDelayed` `Runnable`

  Check if the Dialog has been cancelled, which would indicate a
  finished `HttpURLConnection`/`doInBackground()`

  If it is not cancelled, add a cancel button with a oncancelcallback
  to the dialog, and the oncancelcallback will trigger some code which should be able to cancel the `HttpURLConnection`.

  My problem is that while the `AsyncTask` is running its
  `doInBackground()`, when the cancel button appears on in the dialog
  and is pressed, the oncancelcallback won't excute its code while
  the `doInBackground()` is still doing its `HttpURLConnection` stuff. It
  will wait for the `doInBackground()` to finish and then execute its
  code, which obviates its purpose.

Comment: Please post your codes.

Comment: `doInBackground` is run on a different thread than the UI so the cancel callback will be executed regardless of what `doInBackground` does. How do you try to stop the AsyncTask?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto I'd love to, but this is a lot of code spread among multiple files. To me it's not worth the effort to create a code-summary for this purpose. I've now even dumped the cancel functionality completely, but I'll still track this question for future reference.

Comment: @StenSoft It is not yet clear how I can cancel the `AsyncTask`, currently, just for checking what works, I'm placing the `HttpURLConnection` into a global variable on which I then call `_global_connection.disconnect()` in the `oncancelcallback`. But when I check the the value of `_global_connection`, it's already null, which is the result of disconnect already having been called in the `doInBackground()` (I set it to null after that disconnect).

Comment: You can't use a variable from two threads at the same time. That has undefined behaviour. To cancel an AsyncTask, call it's method `cancel` and check for `isCancelled` in `doInBackground`.

Comment: I'm trying to cancel a single, possibly long-running `HttpURLConnection`. That would require me to be able to poll for `isCancelled`, which I can't do since the `HttpURLConnection` will be blocking the `doInBackground`. Or am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: You can call `cancel(true)` to interrupt all IO. It will throw `InterruptedException` in that case. But you should still check for `isCancelled` if you are e.g. processing large amounts of data.

Comment: @StenSoft Thanks, I'll try that, but don't have time ATM. I'll post back later.